# Install package from github into Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, github, package, spyder

I have been trying to install and import the `mpl_finance` package, from github,  on my Spyder environment with no success.

I have tried:

```
pip install -e \ git+https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance.git
```

But getting:

```
Directory '\\' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

I do not understand the error. Am I not specifying something? I also tried below with no sucess.

```
!pip install -e \ git+https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance.git#eggs=matplotlib

pip install -e \ git+https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance
```

The package is located [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance).

Comment: Did you try `pip install mpl_finance` ? The package is on the python package index so there should not be any need to load it from GitHub.

Comment: Yes, and get the error: `Collecting mpl_finance
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_finance (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpl_finance`

Comment: Ok, so what is the ` \ ` doing in your call? I would think you need `pip install -e  git+https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance.git#egg=mpl_finance`. Alternatively, just download the package from the web using your browser and run setup.py. As a last resort, simply copy the `mpl_finance.py` into your python path.

Comment: Now I get `Invalid requirement: 'mpl_fi??nance'`. I didn't want to do the manual part. But it seems I'm heading in that direction.