# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '' [Python]

Tags: python, github, anaconda

I am new to Python, I normally use MATLAB for statistical analysis, so I am a total beginner.

I am trying to use this library from GitHub `https://github.com/sander-sn/anatomy`https://github.com/sander-sn/anatomy

I have downloaded Python today by using Anaconda, through Anaconda, I am using `Spyder`

The pacakge author suggests using

```
pip install anatomy
```

Into the `Spyder` console, I type the following, `pip install anatomy`

This appears to work fine, as it returns the following output in the console,

```
pip install anatomy
Requirement already satisfied: anatomy in c:\users\sampy\src\anatomy (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.15.0 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from anatomy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.1 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from anatomy) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.0 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from anatomy) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0.0->anatomy) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0.0->anatomy) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\sampy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=1.0.0->anatomy) (1.16.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

However, the authors of the code, provides an example file to run, I open this in `Spyder`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Nov 25 13:55:12 2022

@author: sampy
"""
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from anatomy import *

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


def train_ols(x_train: pd.DataFrame, y_train: pd.Series) -> AnatomyModel:
    ols_model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)

    def pred_fn_ols(xs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        xs_df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=x_train.columns)
        return np.array(ols_model.predict(xs_df)).flatten()

    return AnatomyModel(pred_fn_ols)


def train_rf(x_train: pd.DataFrame, y_train: pd.Series) -> AnatomyModel:
    rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1338).fit(x_train, y_train)

    def pred_fn_rf(xs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        xs_df = pd.DataFrame(xs, columns=x_train.columns)
        return np.array(rf_model.predict(xs_df)).flatten()

    return AnatomyModel(pred_fn_rf)


def generate_data() -> [pd.DataFrame, AnatomySubsets]:

    xy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (500, 3)), columns=["x_0", "x_1", "x_2"])
    xy["y"] = xy.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(0, 1, 500)

    # set a unique and monotonically increasing index (default index would suffice):
    xy.index = pd.date_range("2021-04-19", "2022-08-31").map(lambda x: x.date())

    subsets = AnatomySubsets.generate(
        index=xy.index,
        initial_window=100,
        estimation_type=AnatomySubsets.EstimationType.EXPANDING,
        periods=1,
        gap=0
    )

    return xy, subsets


def estimate_anatomy(xy: pd.DataFrame, subsets: AnatomySubsets) -> None:

    def mapper(key: AnatomyModelProvider.PeriodKey) -> \
            AnatomyModelProvider.PeriodValue:
        train = xy.iloc[subsets.get_train_subset(key.period)]
        test = xy.iloc[subsets.get_test_subset(key.period)]

        if key.model_name == "ols":
            model = train_ols(train.drop("y", axis=1), train["y"])
        elif key.model_name == "rf":
            model = train_rf(train.drop("y", axis=1), train["y"])

        return AnatomyModelProvider.PeriodValue(train, test, model)

    provider = AnatomyModelProvider(
        n_periods=subsets.n_periods,
        n_features=xy.shape[1] - 1,
        model_names=["ols", "rf"],
        y_name="y",
        provider_fn=mapper
    )

    Anatomy(provider=provider, n_iterations=10).precompute(
        n_jobs=max(1, min(os.cpu_count(), 16)), save_path="anatomy.bin"
    )


def anatomize(xy: pd.DataFrame, subsets: AnatomySubsets) -> None:

    anatomy = Anatomy.load("anatomy.bin")

    groups = {
        "rf": ["rf"],
        "ols": ["ols"],
        "ols+rf": ["ols", "rf"]
    }

    def anatomize_r2_oos() -> pd.DataFrame:

        prevailing_mean = np.array([
            xy.iloc[subsets.get_train_subset(period=i)]["y"].mean()
            for i in range(subsets.n_periods)
        ])

        def transform(y_hat, y):
            return 1 - np.sum((y - y_hat) ** 2) / np.sum((y - prevailing_mean) ** 2)

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform)
        )

    def anatomize_rmse() -> pd.DataFrame:

        def transform(y_hat, y):
            return np.sqrt(np.mean((y - y_hat) ** 2))

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform)
        )

    def anatomize_rmse_subperiod() -> pd.DataFrame:

        def transform(y_hat, y):
            return np.sqrt(np.mean((y - y_hat) ** 2))

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform),
            explanation_subset=pd.date_range("2021-07-28", "2021-08-06").map(lambda x: x.date())
        )

    def anatomize_mae() -> pd.DataFrame:

        def transform(y_hat, y):
            return np.mean(np.abs(y - y_hat))

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform)
        )

    def anatomize_se() -> pd.DataFrame:

        def transform(y_hat, y):
            return (y - y_hat) ** 2

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform)
        )

    def anatomize_forecasts() -> pd.DataFrame:

        def transform(y_hat):
            return y_hat

        return anatomy.explain(
            model_sets=AnatomyModelCombination(groups=groups),
            transformer=AnatomyModelOutputTransformer(transform=transform)
        )

    pd.options.display.width = 0  # to print all columns

    tmpl = "contributions to %s:"

    print(tmpl % "out-of-sample R²")
    print(anatomize_r2_oos(), "\n")

    print(tmpl % "root mean squared error")
    print(anatomize_rmse(), "\n")

    print(tmpl % "root mean squared error (subperiod)")
    print(anatomize_rmse_subperiod(), "\n")

    print(tmpl % "mean absolute error")
    print(anatomize_mae(), "\n")

    print(tmpl % "squared errors")
    print(anatomize_se(), "\n")

    print(tmpl % "forecasts")
    print(anatomize_forecasts(), "\n")


def main():

    # set random seed for reproducibility:
    np.random.seed(1338)

    # first generate data from the simple linear dgp:
    xy, subsets = generate_data()

    # next estimate the models and the anatomy, which is stored as "anatomy.bin" in the current working directory:
    estimate_anatomy(xy, subsets)

    # finally load "anatomy.bin" and anatomize the estimated models on a multitude of metrics:
    anatomize(xy, subsets)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error message

```
`runfile('C:/Users/sampy/.spyder-py3/test_anatomy.py', wdir='C:/Users/sampy/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sampy\.spyder-py3\test_anatomy.py", line 11, in <module>
    from anatomy import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anatomy'
```

To use a GitHub package, do I need to do anything further than use the pip install method?

I tried *naively* to add a line of text to the code import anatomy with no success.

Comment: Why do you use the `-e` option for `pip`? I'm not sure why you need it. Leave it away. And then just show us the output of `python3 -c "import anatomy"`. Maybe there is a virtual environment involved from Spyder or Anaconda? You should not use Spyder or Anaconda when you are new to Python. Use a (simple) text editor and and the commandline first.

Comment: @buhtz I used -e following this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115167/install-package-from-github-into-spyder

Comment: As a complete novice, I do not know how to use a simple text editor, but I will certainly have a look around the internet and get back to you! I was using Spyder as I read it was similar to MATLAB. Thanks!

Comment: The post you linked is not valuable and not fitting to your case. Please use the [package owners own install suggestion](https://github.com/sander-sn/anatomy#quickstart) and do it the usual way via `python3 -m pip install anatomy`.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, I am using Spyder, so if I type this in, I get an error message, the package author suggests pip install anatomy, which I try and it works, but I still get the same error message when trying to run the example code

Comment: I have updated the question and used the package authors suggestion, I thought I needed github, but I dont, but my error or not being able to run the code is still present.

Comment: @buhtz the first error in the code comes from `from anatomy import *`, the error I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anatomy'`